# Перевести VALUE в десятичное значение

Tags: sql-server, 1с

Здравствуйте, вытаскиваю запросом цены из `_1SCONST`, некоторые из них представлены в непонятном формате. Гугление намекнуло, что используется 36-ричная система счисления, но перевод из 36 в 10 не дает правильных результатов, к тому же, в некоторых значениях есть русские буквы.
Может кто-то знает как все-таки хранятся там данные?

```
23B = 5.94       
T5 = 90.47    
2YOЦО = 15.54
```

Comment: Тебе лучше здесь вопрос задать http://www.forum.mista.ru/index.php Пользуйся 1С++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот рабочие функции, сам пользовался во времена работы на семерке.

```
// Функия переводит число переданное в параметре
// Значение в строку (либо число) в системе счисления X
// X определяется линой шаблона, представление знаков разрядов
// значение шаблона, где сивол шаблона[k] - есть представление
// Например если шаблон "01", то перевод будет осуществлен в двоичную
// систему счисления, если "01234567", то в восьмиричную
// если "0123456789ABCDEF", то в шестнадцатиричную
// если "ЛИ", то в двоичную, где 0 представлен буквой Л, а 1 буквой И
// вариант шаблона:
//     "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyzАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПР    СТУФХЦЧШЩЬЫЪЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюя!@#$%^&*()_-=+{}[]\|/,.:;'"">        <"
// представит Значение в сто пятидесятишести ричной системе счисления,
// где соответствующий символ шаблона означает соответствующую цифру разряда

Функция Из10в36(Знач Значение, Шаблон="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") Экспорт
Значение = Число(Значение);
Результат="";
Основание = СтрДлина(Шаблон);
Пока Значение>0 цикл
    Остат = Значение%Основание;
    Результат1=Сред(Шаблон,Остат+1,1);
    Значение = (Значение-Остат)/Основание;
    Результат = Результат1 + Результат;
КонецЦикла;
Возврат Результат;
КонецФункции

Функция Из36в10(Стр, Шаблон="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") Экспорт
//HEX: Шаблон = "0123456789ABCDEF"

Стр = ВРег(Стр); // на всякий случай.
ДлинаШаблона = СтрДлина(Шаблон);

ДлинаСтроки = СтрДлина(Стр);
ТекСимвол = ДлинаСтроки;
Результат = 0;

Пока ТекСимвол > 0 Цикл
    ОбработкаПрерыванияПользователя();
    ОбрабатываемыйСимвол = Сред(Стр, ТекСимвол,1);
    Если ОбрабатываемыйСимвол = " " Тогда
        ПозицияВШаблоне = Найти(Шаблон,"0")-1;
        //продолжить;
    иначе
        ПозицияВШаблоне = Найти(Шаблон,ОбрабатываемыйСимвол)-1;
    КонецЕсли;
    //Результат = Результат + (ПозицияВШаблоне * power(ДлинаШаблона,ДлинаСтроки-ТекСимвол));
    Результат = Результат + (ПозицияВШаблоне * POW(ДлинаШаблона,ДлинаСтроки-ТекСимвол));
    ТекСимвол = ТекСимвол - 1;
КонецЦикла;

Возврат(Результат);
КонецФункции
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй 1С++. Здесь есть документация http://www.1cpp.ru/index.php/Main
Например [введите сюда описание ссылки]Прямой доступ через ODBC[1](http://www.1cpp.ru/docum/icpp/html/ODBC.html)

Примеры и сборку с плагинами [OpenConf Light Pack](http://infostart.ru/public/15540/)

Так же можно посмотреть [Code First и Linq to EF на примере 1С версии 7.7 и 8.3 часть I](http://infostart.ru/public/393228/)
Там есть пример работы с _1SCONST

Так же [Эффективное использование MSSQL с помощью ВК 1C++](http://kb.mista.ru/article.php?id=86)

Удобно использовать плагин "Конструктор запросов 1С++".

Там создаются запросы в терминах 1С. Получить реальный запрос можно подключив Отладка(1) перед ВыполнитьИнструкцию

Так же есть недокументированные функции _IdToStr и _StrToId